# Can we use a complete xcode project as submodule?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, static-libraries

Can we add a complete xcode project as submodule to another xcode project?
Something similar to static libraries, but here library is xcode project with .app file.

Comment: if you use git, look at http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: Yes, but it is questionable whether this makes sense. What are you trying to accomplish? What are the components (own libraries, third party libraries, apps) of your project? You are likely better off using an Xcode _Workspace_ and adding projects as you need them.

Comment: I started with one app and that app needs to be used in other app. And the first app calls will be started in appdelegate which I cannot change to other file (may be I may miss some conditions).

Comment: you can have xcode project as part of another xcode project. it was how I manage dependency before I switched to http://cocoapods.org/